# SQL Server 2005, Windows Authentication, Connection String giving error "Login Failed"

Tags: sql-server-2005, connection-string, windows-authentication

I have SQL Server 2005 and Visual Studio 2005  installed on my desktop.
Every time I run SQL Server 2005, I have to go for "***RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR***" manually. I have tried changing the settings but no go. So I do it that way only.
But anyways, that's not the actual issue.

Now when I am making a connection string in Visual Studio- console application for Windows Authentication, it is throwing an error "Login failed".

I am new to .NET

Code is as below:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public class Vin 
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!!!");
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=VinOne; Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Prod", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got It!!!");
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: is this sql server or sql server express?

Comment: Thanks. It's SQL Server 2005 and not server express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to know that this strange situation can be resolved by running the Visual Studio in Admin Mode (by right clicking on the icon and selecting 'Run as Admin") as I was doing with SQL Server 2005.

Thanks a lot to all for your support and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

the SqlConnection object that you are creating is probably incorrect.. The syntax should be something like below:

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
            "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=VinOne;Integrated Security=SSPI");
```

SSPI stands for Security Support Provider Interface (if you are curious)

Also check what user the service runs as, to do this navigate to Run. Type Services.msc and then navigate to SQL server, see the value for Log On As and set it to your currently logged in or whatever user Visual Studio runs under, I am guessing the SQL server currently requires higher privileges.

Hope that works! Good luck..

Comment: Thanks. Nope, it too returned the same error. What I do want to know is, "Running SQL as Administrator" manually everytime, will have any effect on the opening of the Connection with the database or not?